# How to interrupt Main Thread in Visual c++

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++

I am trying to interrupt my main Thread from another thread. When I use Boost I simply do `myThread.interrupt();` but now I want to interrupt the main Thread (that is sleeping) from a `boost::thread` I created.

I get to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287963/id-of-main-thread-in-c) but `std::this_thread` doesn't exists in Visual C++ 2013. Is another way I can get a reference to the main Thread so I can use it later to `yield()` or `interrupt()`?

Comment: The Visual C++ Standard Library has included `std::this_thread` since at least Visual C++ 2012.

Comment: Yes I managed to get it working (forgot to add thread.h) but still no way to access Thread from the ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new `boost::thread` where my main program runs:

```
boost::thread mainThread;

void mainFunction(std::string portNumber){

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    mainThread = boost::thread(mainFunction, argv[1]);
    mainThread.join();
}
```

So I can interrupt the Thread when I want with `mainThread.interrupt()`