# How to find out if we are running in main thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

We can get the id of the main thread by calling `std::this_thread::get_id()` just at the start of the `main` function like [this answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13288025/1097451). We can then store this `id` in a global variable and compare against a call of `std::this_thread::get_id()`.

However, this forces us to change the `main` function. Is there a way to create a *library* function that does this? I was thinking about using a global variable initialized with `std::this_thread::get_id()` expression. Since global variables (variables with static duration) are initialized relatively early it is unlikely (but not impossible, see: [deferred dynamic initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Deferred_dynamic_initialization)) that threads are spawned before these variables are initialized.

I could also initialize the global variable with a helper function which enumerates all threads and picks the one with the earliest creation time (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1969662/1097451)).

I am very new to multithreading so any advice or guidance is extremely welcome.

Comment: Why?  What difference does it make what thread any particular function call is running on?

Comment: what is the purpouse for that?, in your code you should know if a function is called on the main thread or not, easy as that. :)

Comment: I'd really suggest sticking to the first answer and modify main. You could create a library which has like an `init` function you can call to main which does all sorts of stuff (including grabbing the main thread ID). That gives you one line of boilerplate to deal with in each main entry point. It doesn't get much more practical than that IMO -- relying on techniques to try to avoid this one-liner can get you in trouble.

Comment: @DanielSanchez Sometimes it's useful for sanity checks, e.g. It's not always so easy if you are designing a general-purpose library, e.g., to know what thread is going to call a function. The library in that case would be decoupled from any particular thread and its functions could potentially be called from any thread.

Comment: @AndrewHenle and Daniel: That is a good point, I will discuss this with my colleagues.

Comment: It's a very rare case and probably the result of a compromise in thread-safety, but occasionally an interface function only makes sense to be called from a specific thread (main or not -- but something predetermined), yet it could be accessible to all. In that case there's no compile-time safety feature to prevent other threads from accessing this function. We could try to get all elaborate and try to find a way to reduce visibility of this function one thread, but sometimes it's useful to simply turn that into a run-time assertion. Simply `assert` that the current thread is the one expected.

Comment: Though typically in my case, it wasn't actually the main thread, per se. It was more like, "This object isn't thread safe. Make sure all of its methods are invoked by the thread that actually created it." So typically the thread ID would be captured in the ctor in my case, and used for debug-only sanity checks in its methods.

Comment: In Windows the process can outlive the main thread and spawn more threads. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/27/10054832.aspx What if your library is loaded by a secondary thread *after* the main thread has been terminated?

Comment: You will get much better answers if you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve rather than asking for help implementing your chosen solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such thing as main thread. There is a thread which was launched first, but all threads are first-class citizens. By tinkering with linker flags, I can easily create a program where the thread executing `main()` would not be the the thread launched first.

Rethink your design.

Comment: I almost agree.  Without linker flags, in Windows, you can `ExitThread` in the thread that runs `WinMain`, and in POSIX, you can `pthread_exit` in the thread that runs `main`.  The first thread may not exist anymore when a library is loaded.  However, even with a raw program entry point in both systems, you can't avoid the fact that it runs **after** libraries have been loaded and initialized.

Comment: @PauloMadeira, loading and initializing libraries is a big topic, especially with lazy binding :) Luckily, I didn't mention that in my answer - I was only saying about the thread executing `main()`.

Comment: You're right, you can have a raw entry point that runs `main` or `WinMain` in another thread.

Comment: FYI "main thread" (aka "UI thread") is the terminology used on iOS/macOS.

Comment: @Jyaif see neither of those tags in the question.

Comment: Apparently this is different in Windows: Per [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugeventex), "Only the thread that created the process being debugged can call WaitForDebugEventEx".

Comment: It is sometimes important to identify if you are on "the thread that launched first". [Some O/S do not allow interaction with the UI](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#Threads) if you are not on the main thread

Answer (score 9):

EDIT

This is not a solid way of getting the main thread's ID considering what @ta.speot.is and @David Schwartz said.

You could make a static variable somewhere that initializes with the current thread's ID.

```
const std::thread::id MAIN_THREAD_ID = std::this_thread::get_id();
```

And then somewhere else:

```
if (std::this_thread::get_id() == MAIN_THREAD_ID)
{
    std::cout << "main thread\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "not main thread\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was the first thing that I considered, however, the problem is that I do not have the guarantee that `MAIN_THREAD_ID` will be initialized in the main thread. Or do I???

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962880/is-c-static-member-variable-initialization-thread-safe) So yeah, it should be running on the same thread `main` runs on.

Comment: Hm works for me in Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10 in a normal Console application.

Comment: This won't work. For one thing, thread IDs can be re-used. "Once a thread has finished, the value of std::thread::id may be reused by another thread."

Comment: Isn't the thread id re-used only when the thread finishes its execution? Which is when the program ends, OP didn't mention persitence outside of life-time of application.

Comment: @Neijwiert Why do you say "which is when the program ends"? A program doesn't terminate until it calls an exit function or all threads terminate. (Also, I can't find any specific guarantee that static objects are initialized by the same thread as calls `main`.)

Comment: I retract my statement and it is undeed not a solid way of testing if it is the main thread.

Comment: Think about a DLL that is loaded some time after the process is already running.  Its initialization occurs in the thread that invoked `LoadLibrary` (or alike).  Moreover, like @ta.speot.is says in the question's comments, in Windows you can exit the first thread without exiting the process (using the native `WinMain` entry point, not the C/C++'s `main` entry point), so what thread qualifies as the main thread after this?

Comment: @PauloMadeira, I can achieve the same effect in *Nix by tinkering with linker flags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MFC. You can check `AfxGetMainWnd()`. If it return a pWnd then you have the (MFC) main thread. Disclaimer: If you have not manipulatued the `m_pMainWnd` Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

void check_thread() {
    if (syscall(SYS_gettid) == getpid()) {
        printf("Hello from main thread\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Hello from child thread\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    check_thread();
    std::thread t(check_thread);
    t.join();
}
```